# galaxy s5 says battery temperature too high too low!

Tags: battery

help me please. my galaxy s5 won't charge it says the battery temperature is too high or too low. i used to change my battery but when the new battery runs out of life and when i try to charge it, the same problem exist. what can I do? any helps or suggestion please. thank you.

Comment: I posted my answer over there too in case it's duplicate. There was hardly any useful info over there for how many views it has.

Answer (score 0):

I have an S5 also, I haven't had this problem. I have extra batteries along with an external wall charger.

I use the wall charger to avoid charging my phone. It was $15 on ebay, and it may be a viable workaround and/or solution outside of replacing the motherboard.

These wall chargers will charge your battery no matter what, you can confirm this by looking at the pins on the image below. **If the third pin not present**, the charger does not check battery stats before charging.

[image]

(I consider this a solution, because we'll be taking advantage of the removable battery feature, and the chargers come in packs of three batteries so you'll never be stuck to an outlet again. I recommend labeling each battery with lines around the curved edges.)

Anyway, hope this helps.